# How to test if a graph is fully connected and finding isolated graphs from an adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, algorithms

I have large sparse adjacency matrices that may or maybe not be fully connected. I would like to find out if a matrix is fully connected or not and if it is, which groups of nodes belong to a group/cluster. I have an example matrix:

```
matnew =
 0     1     1     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

There are bi-directional edges and directed edges which belong to 2 separate clusters: $1\leftrightarrow 2$, $1\leftrightarrow 3$, $3\rightarrow 4$, and in the next cluster $5\leftrightarrow 6$, $5\rightarrow 7$, $7\rightarrow 6$.

The first approach is to use a function to calculate the paths between nodes

```
>> floyd_warshall_all_sp(sparse(matnew))
ans =
 0     1     1     2   Inf   Inf   Inf
 1     0     2     3   Inf   Inf   Inf
 1     2     0     1   Inf   Inf   Inf
Inf   Inf   Inf     0   Inf   Inf   Inf
Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf     0     1     1
Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf     1     0     2
Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf     2     1     0
```

That works great by looking off the diagonal for `Inf` and then clustering, but my matrices are in the size of thousands of nodes and it is slow (too slow for my needs). **Is there a method/algorithm which just checks connectivity?***

I thought about checking the walk lengths as an approximation, but to be certain I would have to guess that they are not more than a number of jumps eg 10. Which may be reasonable but even then doing the matrix multiplication of a 1000x1000 many times is not so great for an approximation.

```
>> (matnew^1)+(matnew^2)+(matnew^3)+(matnew^4)+(matnew)^5
ans =
 6     7     7     3     0     0     0
 7     3     3     3     0     0     0
 7     3     3     4     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     5     7     4
 0     0     0     0     4     5     3
 0     0     0     0     3     4     2
```

But it does reveal quite a bit about the connectivity.

Comment: Have you heard about [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)? Also, matrix multiplication is rather slow, but if you want to stick with it (e.g. you have some special algorithm for your case of spare matrix), you could just do with squaring $(A+I)$, that is, $((((A+I)^2)^2 \cdots)^2)$.

Comment: @dtldarek, you mean by recursively squaring $(A+I)$ I can get higher powers more quickly so that for instance 5 multiplication give $2^8$ walk length? I hadn't thought of `DFS`... I should have though, thanks

Comment: @dtldarek, I tried to use some DFS and Dijkstra but they don't seem to look from each node, they appear to find a node with a lead and don't find the other isolated island of nodes

Comment: I found this file which is relatively quick for Dijkstra http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20025 and is as fast as squaring 4 times recusively on a 2000x2000 adjacency matrix

Comment: Why would you use Dijkstra? The point of DFS is just to visit nodes, all you can visit generate one connected component. Then start with another, not-yet-visited node and search for corresponding group (that is all nodes that are reachable from the new starting vertex).

Comment: This link is also useful; http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/240766

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what language are you using, but in [ruby](http://tryruby.org) it would look like this (for an input given by adjacency lists):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8

def dfs_run(graph, visited, start)
  return [] if visited[start]
  visited[start] = true
  output = [start]
  graph[start].each do |neighbour|
    output += dfs_run(graph, visited, neighbour)
  end
  output
end

def weakly_connected_components(input_graph)

  # make the graph undirected
  graph = input_graph.clone
  input_graph.each do |vertex, neighbours|
    neighbours.each do |n| graph[n] += [vertex] end
  end
  graph.each do |vertex, neighbours|
    neighbours.sort!
    neighbours.uniq!
  end

  # run dfs
  output = []
  visited = {}
  graph.keys.each do |vertex|
    output << dfs_run(graph, visited, vertex).sort unless visited[vertex]
  end

  # return an array of wcc
  output
end

# an example
graph = {0=>[1, 2, 3, 5], 1=>[0, 2, 3], 2=>[0, 1, 3, 5], 3=>[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], 4=>[0], 5=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 6=>[0, 2, 3, 5], 7=>[8], 8=>[0], 9=>[]}
# transformed to the following undirected graph: {0=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8], 1=>[0, 2, 3, 5], 2=>[0, 1, 3, 5, 6], 3=>[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], 4=>[0, 3, 5], 5=>[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 6=>[0, 2, 3, 5], 7=>[8], 8=>[0, 7], 9=>[]}


print weakly_connected_components(graph), "\n"
# outputs [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The second smallest eigenvector (Fiedler vector) of the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) can be used to reveal information about the number of disconnected components.