# Power of adjacency matrix

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, exponentiation, adjacency-matrix

What does ij element of the k-th power of adjacency matrix for a directed graph, i.e. A^k represent: number of paths with exact k length or number of paths with length k or less than k from i to j?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the precise meaning of "path".

The standard definition (to the extent that there is a 'standard' one) is that a **walk** is any  alternating sequence of vertices and edges, consecutive elements of which are incident, that begins and ends with a vertex. With that definition:

The number of walks of length $k$ between nodes $i$ and $j$ in a graph is **precisely** given by the $i,j$ element of $A^k$.

The standard definition of **path** is that it is a walk without repeated vertices. That was the definition used in the post to which you refer. With this definition of path, having a non-zero $i,j$ element means that you can get from $i$ to $j$ in $k$ steps but you may have repeated a vertex. In that case you  know that there is a path from $i$ to $j$ (by shortening the walk of length $k$) but that it's length is less than $k$.

Answer (score 0):

''number of paths with exact k length or number of paths with length k or less than k from i to j?''

Number of paths of length $k$ between nodes $i$ and $j$ in a graph given by its adjacency matrix.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864604/checking-connectivity-of-adjacency-matrix   - Doesn't the answer in this question suggest it to be less than equal to k?